# How to dump a dict to a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dict like this:

```
sample = {'ObjectInterpolator': 1629,  'PointInterpolator': 1675, 'RectangleInterpolator': 2042}
```

I can't figure out how to dump the dict to a JSON file as showed below:

```
{      
    "name": "interpolator",
    "children": [
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
}
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

You may guess that I want to generate a `d3` treemap.

Comment: is it possible for you to accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 772):

```
import json
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(sample, fp)
```

This is an easier way to do it.

In the second line of code the file `result.json` gets created and opened as the variable `fp`.

In the third line your dict `sample` gets written into the `result.json`!

Comment: @Fermi the result JSON is sorted one.how can I stop this sortin while dumping it into a JSON

Comment: @Danish Don't know. Unless there is a question already on SO about  your problem, you should create a new question describing your issue. (btw, i m simply an editor of those posts)

Comment: I also dont know. Just ask a new question like Fermi proposed.

Comment: Tip : If you don't want to write to a file, and only see the output, try redirecting it to 

`stdout: json.dump('SomeText', sys.stdout)`

Comment: @Dan-ish Have you tried json.dump(sample, fp, sort_keys=False ) ? Assuming I understand what you mean.

Comment: Good thing to remember here is that unless you use an `OrderedDict` (python >2.7) there is no guarantee that keys are ordered in any particular manner

Comment: It throws " dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" error

Comment: @Vijay, the function is called `dump` (not `dumps`).

Comment: What if my values of dictionary is a Set() ,

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Note that you can pass the 'indent' parameter (usually 2 or 4 is recommended) to `dump()`, so your JSON file is human readable.

Comment: json file automatically get prepand with `\n` for each value while using `json.dump`, how we can avoid that ?

Comment: @ArindamRoychowdhury
Or you can just use print(json.dumps('SomeText'))

Answer (score 58):

Combine the answer of @mgilson and @gnibbler, I found what I need was this:

```py
d = {
    "name": "interpolator",
    "children": [{
        'name': key,
        "size": value
        } for key, value in sample.items()]
    }
j = json.dumps(d, indent=4)
with open('sample.json', 'w') as f:
    print >> f, j
```

It this way, I got a pretty-print json file.
The tricks `print >> f, j` is found from here:
http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2012/03/11/generate-json-from-sql-using-python/

Comment: `print(j, file=f)` in Python 3.6 (instead of `print >> f, j`)

Comment: `print(j, file=f)` didn't work for me,I didn't need to do the J part as well. `d = {'a':1, 'b':2}    print(d,  file=open('sample.json', 'wt'))` worked.

Comment: You can also use `indent` to create formatted dump: `json.dump(content, file, indent=4)`

Comment: `indent=4`, that's the stuff I was looking for!

Answer (score 29):

```
d = {"name":"interpolator",
     "children":[{'name':key,"size":value} for key,value in sample.items()]}
json_string = json.dumps(d)
```

Since python 3.7 the ordering of dicts is retained https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

> Dictionaries preserve insertion order. Note that updating a key does not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the end

Comment: json_string = json.dumps(d, , sort_keys=True) if sorted order is desired.

Answer (score 23):

Also wanted to add this (Python 3.7)

```
import json

with open("dict_to_json_textfile.txt", 'w') as fout:
    json_dumps_str = json.dumps(a_dictionary, indent=4)
    print(json_dumps_str, file=fout)
```

**Update (11-04-2021):** So the reason I added this example is because sometimes you can use the `print()` function to write to files, and this also shows how to use the indentation (unindented stuff is evil!!). *However* I have recently started learning about threading and some of my research has shown that the `print()` statement is not always thread-safe. So if you need threading you might want to be careful with this one.

Answer (score 18):

with pretty-print format:

```
import json

with open(path_to_file, 'w') as file:
    json_string = json.dumps(sample, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
    file.write(json_string)
```

Comment: you can supply all those parameters to `dump(sample, file, ...)` too. The extra step of writing to a string is not needed. `dump` internally writes in chunks. This could be more efficient than to compile a (possibly huge) string first.

Answer (score 17):

This should give you a start

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps([{'name': k, 'size': v} for k,v in sample.items()], indent=4)
[
    {
        "name": "PointInterpolator",
        "size": 1675
    },
    {
        "name": "ObjectInterpolator",
        "size": 1629
    },
    {
        "name": "RectangleInterpolator",
        "size": 2042
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths):

```py
Path('result.json').write_text(json.dumps(sample, indent=4) + '\n')
```