# Import a exported dict into python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm writing something like a database, but rather simple and small. So I used a dict, which is then saved in a file.

The code is roughly:

```
d = {'apple': 1, 'bear': 2}
print(d, file=f)
```

I want it to be imported the next time I run it, i.e. import it as a dictionary from file, anyway to do it?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix is there any way to make it readable externally with notepad or gedit?

Comment: have you tried to open your file? is it in shape of dictionary or is it like: `apple 1 , bear  2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dump dict to json file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/python-dump-dict-to-json-file)

Comment: also you can use eval construction.. d = eval(open(filename, 'rb').read())

Comment: @KevinGuan I'm not familiar with json files, however, if that's a good way I'd flag mine as duplicated

Comment: or save the dict as json, if you need human-readable data (otherwise Pickle approach is better). In you simple example you can do like this: `import json; json.load(f)`

Comment: @AntonBarycheuski `eval()` is really dangerous. use `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` here is the best way.

Comment: @AntonBarycheuski No. Eval is completely unnecessary (not to mention potentially dangerous)

Comment: @YiFei Well, let me post an answer with a simple example about how to use `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Eval is not recommened, it is dangerous, INSTEAD, one can use literal eval with importing ast, `import ast

def reading(self):
    s = open('file', 'r').read()
    self.whip = ast.literal_eval(s)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like save some data such as `list`, `dict` or `tuple`, etc. to a file. And you want to edit them or you just want them be *readable* . Use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'apple': 1, 'bear': 2}

>>> print(d)
{'bear': 2, 'apple': 1}

>>> print(json.dumps(d))
{"bear": 2, "apple": 1}  # these are json data
>>>
```

Now you could save these data to a file. If you want to load them, use `json.loads()` like this:

```
>>> json_data = '{"bear": 2, "apple": 1}'
>>> d = json.loads(json_data)
>>> d['bear']
2
>>>
```

Comment: So can json be in-placed written when something dynamic involved?

Comment: Maybe you'd like take a look about [**Json Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) :)

Comment: Also the *Python document of Json* that I've linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        d = ast.literal_eval(line)
        # do things.
```