# Converting a list of dicts into dict of dicts to send a "complex" json to cloudant

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, cloudant

Hello and good year 2017 to everyone!

I have issues to send a quiet complex json to a cloudant DB.
As far as I understand (and it's not really far because i'm a total newbie), the only way to send a file on the cloudant DB with cloudant for python is to make a variable "data"

```
data = {
    '_ID': 'userInfo',
    'Name': 'Manu'
    'Age': 23,
    'Hobbies': ['cloudant', 'python', 'dockers']
    }
```

and to use the command

```
my_document = my_database.create_document(data)
```

which succesfully create a file in the DB.

BUT it looks like everything goes trickier when the data is not inside a dict, because at somepoint the .create_document() method try to extract keys and values and it goes wild when you give him a list
link to console error: https://www.jepix.fr/images/cloudanterror.png

but it's not a regular list that I try to give him, it's a magnificent list of dicts :-)

```
[
   {dict1},
   {dict2},
   {dict3},
   {dict4},
   { },
   { },
   { },
   { },
   { }
]
```

with marvelous dicts inside the dicts :-D
I think I need a way to convert the list of dicts into a dict of dicts and I ABSOLUTELY HAVE TO keep this dict structure because it is use by other colleagues' templates, parser etc. or my apprentice's bottom will be kicked ruthlessly!

```
import cloudant
import json
from cloudant.client import Cloudant


client = Cloudant("USR", "PWD", url)
client.connect()

# Client tasks ##########################################
session = client.session()
print 'Username: {0}'.format(session['userCtx']['name'])
print 'Databases: {0}'.format(client.all_dbs())

my_db = client['scenario-json']

with open('scenarioGenerated.json', 'r') as fp:
    json_str = fp.read()

json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
my_doc = my_db.create_document(json_dict)



client.disconnect()
```

I have tried total newbie's desperate move like casting the list into dict with dict() function but I got an argument error telling me I have not enough argument to call this function (at this point I awfully accepted it and searched for another way out)

I also tried the json library for python with json.load/.loads/.dump/.dumps but it's the same problem as it convert the json to a string (looping back on the "str" object has no "get" attribute error)

I saw maybe a solution on an overflow post: [Python dump dict to json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/python-dump-dict-to-json-file)

But I need to do the opposite, like reading the json and fill in a dict? 
I don't think it's the cleverest moves as the dict-filling process can loose the dict hierarchy...

So imo, if you have a nice way to convert the list of dicts into a dict of dicts it would be so nice!

Sorry for the long post and very noobish question but i'm like a plankton in a sea of whales and it's not a good situation :-p

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, so that u can get help here

Comment: Don't know anything about Cloudant, but the [documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html) says that other than the mandatory `_id` and `_rev` field, documents can contain just about any other JSON you want. So wouldn't something like `{ "_id": "foo", "_rev": "bar", "my_array": [ ... ] }` be better?

Comment: @SivaCn done, this is supposed to work because that's what I did when I was training with socket, I used to loads and dumps json as a string to send it through sockets.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you mean building a dict with: 

    data = {
        "_id": "killme",
        "my_array" : the_json_list_of_dicts 
    }

Comment: @Manu Yep, exactly. That way you don't have to change your data structure, you just nest it inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to create all the data in a single call to the `create_document()` function, or can you make multiple calls? If you can do the second, I would write something like this:

```
documents = [ {dict1}, {dict2}, {dict3}, ...]
for document in documents:
    my_document = my_database.create_document(document)
    # Do some more processing.
```

This creates one document for each document in the list.

Following up on the comment by `thissuitisblacknot`, you might be able to do something like this:

```
documents = [ {dict1}, {dict2}, {dict3}, ...]
data = { "docs": documents }
my_database.bulk_create_document(data) # Guessed at bulk_create_document()
```

Comment: There's also apparently a way to do [bulk operations](https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#bulk-operations) to create multiple documents at once.

Comment: Yes I'm supposed to because each data inside each dicts are specific to a device and I can't separate devices :/

Comment: Ok thank you so much guys Simon and @ThisSuitIsBlackNot
it looks like it work and moreover, once the file is upload I can edit it haha :-)

Have a good evening!

Comment: And it works with regular command without bulk (and it's nice because I don't know bulk yet) 

And it's even easier to load back the json as it's just a value of a key, wonderful ^_^

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Easy but quite unnecessary would be to just put a dict around the whole list. So a dict with one key and one element. That one element being your list... I Dont see why you have this structure though and why this is how it needs to be, so its hard for me to help out any other way.

Comment: I have to keep this structure because it's a simulation scenario where each elements of the json goes through a template, then the template's var are used by the program to create a payload sent to a mqtt broker :/

I'm a begginer and it sounds so crazy to be on this but thanks for your comment I'm going to try that and keep you in touch :)