# Add single quotes to a variable in Python

Tags: python

I have a variable  that looks like this:

```
data = {"add_content": {"errata_ids": [advisory]},"content_view_version_environments": [{"content_view_version_id": version_id}]}
```

I need to add single quotes to this variable , i.e. if I will assign the variables:

`advisory` and `version_id` and add the single quotes to data variable like this:

```
data = '{"add_content": {"errata_ids": ["RHSA-2017:1390"]},"content_view_version_environments": [{"content_view_version_id": 160}]}'
```

I am able to post to the API

I have tried to add the single quotes in variety of ways:

```
new_data = "'" + str(data) + "'"
>>> new_data
'\'{\'add_content\': {\'errata_ids\': [\'"RHSA-2017:1390"\']}, \'content_view_version_environments\': [{\'content_view_version_id\': \'160\'}]}\''
```

or using:

```
'"%s"'%(data)
```

and a few more ways.

How can I add the single quotes to the outer to the data variable before and after the opening `{` and closing `}`?

Comment: What you're trying to create is JSON, so use the `json` module.

Comment: Python's string representation of a `dict` instance isn't necessarily valid JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dump dict to json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/python-dump-dict-to-json-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what JSON does:

```
import json
new_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If in contrary of previous answers and comments you are not trying to convert to a json string then use string.format around the variables:

```
data = {"add_content": {"errata_ids": '[{}]'.format(advisory)},"content_view_version_environments": [{"content_view_version_id": '{}'.format(version_id)}]}
```