# Facing a issue in json file using Python

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and Json. I am trying to convert xml content into json using python.

i have an xml file with as below:

```
<pins>
        <pin name="PA3">
            <pinNumber package="QFN64" value="1"/>
            <pinAlias alias="PA3" module="GPIO"/>
.....
```

I am able to generate json file using xmltodict in python created as shown below:

```
{
  "device": {
    "pins": {
      "pin": [
        {
          "pinAlias": [
            {
              "alias": "PA3", 
              "module": "GPIO"
            }, ......
```

But i need to generate the json file as:

```
{
  "device": {
    "pins": [
        {
          "pinAlias": [
            {
              "alias": "PA3", 
              "module": "GPIO"
            },....
```

Can anyone help me in achieving this?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before. Please see if <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/how-to-dump-a-dict-to-a-json-file> solves your problem first, then update your question  to point out the differences if it does not. Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dump a dict to a json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/how-to-dump-a-dict-to-a-json-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data structure is named `d`:

```
d['pins'] = d['pins']['pin']
```