# pythin: how do I convert string to json python

Tags: python

I have below data , how can I convert user data to json in python?

```
results= [
            {
                "created_at": 1632712032050,
                "user": "{\"id\": \"12\", \"name\": \"test\"}"
            },
            {
                "created_at": 1632712032050,
                "user": "{\"id\": \"13\", \"name\": \"test\"}"
            }
         ]
```

expected output:

```
results= [
            {
                "created_at": 1632712032050,
                "user": {"id": "12", "name": "test"}
            },
            {
                "created_at": 1632712032050,
                "user": {"id": "13", "name": "test"}
            }
         ]
```

Comment: Did you check the `json` module?

Comment: Read this, https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dump a dict to a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/how-to-dump-a-dict-to-a-json-file)

Comment: check my answer it outputs your expected format

Comment: You are trying to *parse* JSON, not create it.

Comment: try `import json; json_str = json.dumps(data_structure_root)` to convert data structure to json string. The inverse operation of converting a json string into a data structure is `data_structure_root = json.loads(json_str)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the json module of python

```
import json

results= [
            {
                "created_at": 1632712032050,
                "user": "{\"id\": \"12\", \"name\": \"test\"}"
            }
         ]

print(results) #in string format

results[0]['user'] = json.loads(results[0]['user'])

print(results) #after parsing its now json dictionary/object
```

Comment: You actually did the *opposite* of what the OP asked for, but the OP is confused and asked for the opposite of what they actually need

Comment: yeah you are right, i did realized that