# Is there a way to generate nested json from a multi-index dataframe in pandas?

Tags: json, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple levels of index. I would like to output it as nested json for consumption by other scripts.  Here is a simple example

[image]

I would like to output the above image as

```
{
  "a": {
    "1": {"foo":6, "bar": 0}, 
    "2": {"foo":0, "bar": 2}, 
    "3": {"foo":5, "bar": 0}
  },
  "b": {
    "1": {/*...*/}, 
    "2": {/*...*/}, 
    "3": {/*...*/}
  },
  "c": {/*...*/},
}
```

Unfortunately just using .to_json() gives me two objects with the values of the columns, which isn't very useful to my consuming script

[image]

I can get closer if I transpose it first, but I still lack the desired nesting.

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this? I'm trying to google the results but all the suggestions I'm finding are about READING nested json.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/how-to-dump-a-dict-to-a-json-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dump a dict to a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/how-to-dump-a-dict-to-a-json-file)